# WordPress Toggle Sidebar SubMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a WordPress site with a menu in the sidebar. I am trying make the "sub-menu" part toggle. The toggle works, however it is toggling the sub-menu when the sub-menu items themselves are clicked not just the parent and therefore the links for the sub-menu items aren't working.

This is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#sidebar .menu .sub-menu').hide();
    jQuery('li.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

And this is the HTML (I'm trying to toggle the "ul.sub-menu" part):

```
<aside id="sidebar">
    <div id="nav_menu-6" class="widget widget_nav_menu"><h3>Athletics</h3>
        <div class="menu-athletics-container">
            <ul id="menu-athletics" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-641" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-32 current_page_item menu-item-641"><a href="http://web2.gradelink.com/747/athletics/">Athletics</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-664" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-664 parent"><a href="#">Sports</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                        <li id="menu-item-665" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-665"><a href="http://web2.gradelink.com/747/athletics/baseball/">Baseball</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-666" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-666"><a href="http://web2.gradelink.com/747/athletics/basketball/">Basketball</a></li>
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-675" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-675"><a href="http://web2.gradelink.com/747/athletics/athletic-forms-resources/">Athletic Forms &amp; Resources</a></li>
                <!-- ... -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that since the li element was waiting for the click, it applied to the entire element:

[li Parent Object: Inspect Element selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPQDV.png)

I fixed it by applying the click to the link itself, and then using parent and children to backtrack and toggle the sub-menu.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#sidebar .menu .sub-menu').hide();
    jQuery('#sidebar .menu-item-has-children a').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `children` to select any child element with desired class:

```
$('sub-menu').hide();
$('.menu').children().click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.sub-menu li').slideToggle('slow');     
});
```

Comment: How about some added explanation?